# Manipulate the last line matching

Tags: unix

How do I manipulate the last line matching in a text? I have a configuration file in which I wish to change a certain value:

```
val1=0
val2=a
val3=?
val2=lol
```

I only want to change the last line matching the value to grep for. `sed -i 's/\(^val2=\)/\1yes/'` is a good start, but replaces both `val2` lines instead of only the last.

I tagged the question very generically as Unix because I'm open to any solution: sed or awk, Perl or Ruby, Bash or whatever. A shorter solution is sexier than a mouthful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I came up with is this:

```
tac config |while read LINE; do
  if [ "$DONE" != 1 ] && echo "$LINE" |grep '^\s*val2\s*=' >/dev/null; then
    echo "$LINE" |sed 's/^\(\s*val2\s*=\s*\)/\1yes/'
    DONE=1
  else
    echo "$LINE"
  fi
done |tac >config.new
```

But this doesn't feel like the quick-and-dirty pipelines I like for such a common task.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the script found [here](http://www.rtfiber.com.tw/~changyj/sed/html/p.20080923a.html):

```
sed -r ':0;/^val2=/!b;:1;$!N;/\n.*word/{h;s/\n[^\n]*$//p;g;s/^.*\n//};$!b 1;s/^(.*)(val2=)[^\n]*/\1\2yes/' file
```

Comment: I may be getting it wrong, but this seems to omit lines. In a test case I ran I lost the last config line.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I changed the dot near the end to a non-newline `[^\n]`. Try it again.

Answer (score 1):

General idea: read the input in chunks separated by `\nval2=`. Print every chunk as is, except for the last chunk where we change the text up to the first newline. Here's a relatively simple gawk solution that handles most cases:

```
gawk -v 'RS=\nval2=' -v ORS= \
  'RT {print $0 RT} !RT {sub(/[^\n]*/, "yes"); print $0}'
```

This assumes that the first line doesn't start with `val2=` and that there is at least one match. Fixing both defects complicates the script significantly:

```
gawk -v 'RS=\nval2=' -v ORS= \
  '!RT {if (NR==1) sub(/^val2=[^\n]*/, "val2=yes"); else sub(/[^\n]*/, "yes")}
   {print $0 RT}'
```

Here's a Perl solution based on the same general principle, but reading the whole file at once. I find it clearer because it doesn't have to handle special cases (other than the empty file).

```
perl -e 'undef $/;
         @chunks = split /(?=^val2=)/m, <>;
         $chunks[@chunks-1] =~ s/(?<=^val2=).*/yes/ if @chunks;
         print @chunks'
```

With Perl's extended regexps, we can use a single regexp substitution. Just match the `^val2=` that's not followed by another `^val2=`:

```
perl -e 'undef $/; $_=<>; s/^val2=.*\n(?!.*\nval2=)/val2=yes\n/m; print'
```

I tried taking advantage of Python's `rsplit` which can split off the last N fields, but gave up when I couldn't get it to work without being much more cryptic that my Perl solutions.

Comment: Haven't confirmed this works, but: a great answer!